# VB - Insert A Blank Row

Tags: excel, vba

This is child's play for all of you, but I don't know Visual Basic at all.  How do I write a statement to insert a row between two rows in an Excel spreadsheet repeatedly?  An example below:

```
F-3757 - GROF FILTER REWORKLIJN
F-3758 - POEDERAFSCHEIDER
F-3759 - FIJNFILTER
F-3760 - STOFILTER
F-3762 - AANZUIGFILTER
B-3771 - VENTILATOR STORTKOKER
```

to:

```
F-3758 - POEDERAFSCHEIDER

F-3759 - FIJNFILTER

F-3760 - STOFILTER

F-3762 - AANZUIGFILTER

B-3771 - VENTILATOR STORTKOKER
```

Comment: I recommend tagging this 'excel' and 'vba' (or are they the same now? I haven't programmed in VBA in some years).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub Insert_Blank_Rows()  
   ''//Select last row in worksheet.
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select 

   Do Until ActiveCell.Row = 1 
       ''//Insert blank row.
       ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown 
        ''//Move up one row.
       ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select 
    Loop 
 End Sub
```

[VBA Express](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=312#instr) shows an example how to accomplish it